# How to write point-free functional JS using Ramda

Tags: javascript, ramda.js, pointfree

I have an array of objects

```
const myNumbers = [
  {
   top: 10,
   bottom: 5,
   rate: 5
  },
  {
   top: 9,
   bottom: 4,
   rate: 3
  },
];
```

I want to run a few functions that make the numbers usable before I do anything with them;

```
const addTen = r.add(10);
const double = r.multiply(2);
```

And a function that accepts the numbers and does some maths:

```
const process = (top, bottom, rate) => r.multiply(r.subtract(bottom, top), rate)
```

So my final function looks like

```
muNymbers.map(({ top, bottom, rate }) =>
  process(addTen(top), double(bottom), rate)
);
```

Just looking at this code you can see both functions are already becoming very nested and not particularly clear. My real problem is slightly more complicated again, and I am struggling to see how I can make this point-free when picking different values for different operations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is *a* point-free approach. The main functions you're looking for are `pipe`, `evolve` and `converge`. I'm not sure if this is the *best* way, it's just the best I could think of:

```js
const { add, converge, evolve, map, multiply, pipe, prop, subtract } = R;

const myNumbers = [
    { top: 10, bottom: 5, rate: 5 },
    { top: 9, bottom: 4, rate: 3 },
];

const process = pipe(

    evolve({
        top: add(10),
        bottom: multiply(2),
    }),

    converge(multiply, [

        converge(subtract, [
            prop('bottom'),
            prop('top'),
        ]),

        prop('rate'),
    ]),
);

console.log(map(process, myNumbers));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Awesome! That's exactly the sort of thing I was looking for, I just couldn't wrap my head around how to make it work. I tried prop with compose, but I was unable to express myself in a tacit way.

Comment: Yeah that's also what I thought of at first. It's really `converge` that does the trick here, allowing you to apply multiple functions to the same input in 'parallel'. Glad to help you out!

Answer (score 3):

If this is an exercise in writing point-free code, a solution like the one from @JeffreyWesterkamp is fine.

For production code, though, any point-free solution is going to be a *lot* less readable than this simple version:

```js
const process = ({top, bottom, rate}) => ((2 * bottom) - (10 + top)) * rate;

const myNumbers = [
    { top: 10, bottom: 5, rate: 5 },
    { top: 9, bottom: 4, rate: 3 },
];

console.log(R.map(process, myNumbers));
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.js"></script>
```

The point is to not make a fetish over point-free.  It is a tool that sometimes makes code easier to read, easier to understand.  But it's not worth using if it doesn't do so.

Don't get me wrong.  I'm a big fan of point-free code, and Ramda (disclaimer: I'm one of its authors) has some useful tools to help you write it.  But Ramda works just fine with other code.  So use it wisely.

---

One other point (ahem): Ramda supplies two fairly unusual functions, `useWith` and `converge`, to make it easier to write point-free code.  But `converge` can often be replaced by the more standard `lift`. It can't always be replaced, as it has some features for handling variadic functions that `lift` does not supply, but when you can use `lift`, I would suggest that you do so.  For instance, instead of

```
converge(subtract, [prop('bottom'), prop('top')])
```

you might write

```
lift(subtract)(prop('bottom'), prop('top'))
```

There's no standard replacement for `useWith` that I know of.  But I would replace `converge` with `lift` whenever possible.

Comment: Thanks @scott-sauyet for your answer, you have a very strong point about readability. In production code I would probably write something less functional, and more easily maintainable by a team; but I am working on a personal project and wanted to deepen my understanding of point-free code. Playing with Ramda seemed like a good place to start.